# Invalid random.NextDouble values appear when debugging in MonoDevelop

Tags: debugging, mono, monodevelop

Running MonoDevelop 4.0.12 on Linux Mint 17 and coming across a strange problem when using `Random.NextDouble()`.

Consider this:

```
Random r = new Random ();
double dd = r.NextDouble ();
Console.WriteLine (dd);
dd = r.NextDouble ();
Console.WriteLine (dd);
```

**Running** in monodevelop, all is fine

```
0.226428853800577
0.331709416335702
```

(no matter how many times I run it)

Debugging in monodevelop, all is not

```
3.75
0
```

`NextDouble` is suppose to give me a number between 0.0 and 1.0.  Even weirder, the debugger shows the values of 5.25 and 3.5 for the values for the two values of `dd`

Each time I run, the console shows different (wrong) output but the debugger shows the same.

Any ideas?

I'm using libmono-debugger-soft4.0a-cil as the debugger (v3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1).  I've tried building for different versions of .NET and giving an explicate seed to `Random()`, same thing.

```
MonoDevelop
Version 4.0.12
Runtime:
    Mono 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1) (64-bit)
    GTK 2.24.23
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
```

Comment: Is the result "better" when looking at `int dd = (int)(r.NextDouble () * int.MaxValue);` (To try and isolate the value with inspecting the `double` variables or not.)

Comment: That always gives the same value (2147483645) no matter how many times I call it.  Both on display and in the debugger.  When running, it gives 2 different values......  Very strange!

Comment: I got nothing. Works fine in VS :<

Comment: I'm sure it does :).  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all of mono from the official repositories and installed from [this](https://launchpad.net/~ermshiperete/+archive/ubuntu/monodevelop) PPA, all works fine now.

Must be a bug in either monodevelop, debugger or runtime packaged with Mint 17 (Ubuntu 14.04)